# Creating a view in ArcCatalog - ORA-01722

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, oracle-dbms, arccatalog, sql-view

I'm creating a view in ArcCatalog 10.6 on an Oracle DB. Never created a view before but with some Googling, I've managed the SQL below. The view works but only partially. In ArcCatalog, preview shows the first 2000 records. When I click "move to end of table", it gives ORA-01722 error. This happens because the first two characters are not always numeric, some are alpha. I thought using ELSE would calculate them to '9999' but I guess this isn't the case. I need some help where if any of the first two characters are alpha, calculate the value as is, no CONCAT.

```
SELECT GRANTOR, SKETCHNUM, LIBER, FOLIO, CASE 
WHEN SUBSTR(CONTRACT_, 1, 2) BETWEEN 00 AND 20 
THEN CONCAT('20', GISEDITOR.EASEMENTS_ROW.CONTRACT_)
WHEN SUBSTR(CONTRACT_, 1, 2) BETWEEN 21 AND 99
THEN CONCAT('19', GISEDITOR.EASEMENTS_ROW.CONTRACT_)
ELSE '9999'END AS ENGPLANDWG
FROM GISEDITOR.EASEMENTS_ROW
```

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with ArcGIS or GIS -- This an Oracle error, straight-up. I suggest you use an Oracle client to create and display the contents of the view correctly, *then* try to browse it from a GIS client.

Comment: Data issue your trying to convert a string to a number, but there is a value that cannot be translated to a number > http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-01722

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were actually pretty close, and most important the idea is correct. You just needed to compare against characters, remember that characters have an order, and on else case just pass the value as is.

There many ways you can do it. The code I made for you, continue with your idea but instead of checking if is alpha checks if is a digit,

```
SELECT GRANTOR, SKETCHNUM, LIBER, FOLIO, (
    CASE WHEN (
        (SUBSTR(CONTRACT_, 1, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9')
        AND
        (SUBSTR(CONTRACT_, 2, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9')
    ) THEN CONCAT(SUBSTR(CONTRACT_, 1, 2), GISEDITOR.EASEMENTS_ROW.CONTRACT_)
    ELSE CONTRACT_
    END AS ENGPLANDWG
FROM GISEDITOR.EASEMENTS_ROW
```

BTW, I put just one case because I didn't understand whan you finally want to append if success.

Answer (score 1):

This was the end result, thanks again cabesuon.

```
SELECT GRANTOR, SKETCHNUM, LIBER, FOLIO, CONTRACT_,
CASE WHEN (
    (SUBSTR(CONTRACT_, 1, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9')
    AND
    (SUBSTR(CONTRACT_, 2, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9')
    AND
    SUBSTR(CONTRACT_, 1, 2) BETWEEN 00 AND 20)
    THEN CONCAT('20', GISEDITOR.EASEMENTS_ROW.CONTRACT_)
WHEN (
    (SUBSTR(CONTRACT_, 1, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9')
    AND
    (SUBSTR(CONTRACT_, 2, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9')
    AND
    SUBSTR(CONTRACT_, 1, 2) BETWEEN 21 AND 99)
    THEN CONCAT('19', GISEDITOR.EASEMENTS_ROW.CONTRACT_)
ELSE CONTRACT_
END AS ENGPLANDWG
FROM GISEDITOR.EASEMENTS_ROW
```